# Python Traversal for match between 2 files, appending new column with match results

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, compare, traversal

I'm working with 2 dataframes for bike-share information.  One dataframe called 'stations1' is 105 lines long, consisting of bike-share station geographical information: station number, address, latitude and longitude.  The other dataframe called 'trips1' has over 10,000 lines, and consists of trip information for bike-share customers, including start-station number and stop-station number.

I have to use the start-station number on the 'trips1' df and search the 'stations1' for the matching station number until I find a match, and append the station's latitude and longitude addresses to the 'trips' dataframe.

Below is sample code for the dataframes I'm working with.  I have to match the start station number in the trips1 file with the station number in the stations1 file, and append the corresponding 'lat' and 'lng' values on to the trips1 dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [[31111, 38.917, -77.025],[31602, 38.931, -77.031],[31110, 38.923,-77.501], [31107, 38.915, -77.038]]
labels = ['number','lat','lng']
stations1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=labels)
stations1.head()


data2 = [[31602, 31111, 2],[31111, 31110, 3],[31111, 31111, 4], [31111,31107, 1], [31107, 31110, 3], [31110, 31602, 3]]
labels = ['start_station_number', 'end_station_number', 'hours_used']
trips1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=labels)
trips1.head()
```

I'm a novice with Python, so I'm unsure how to start my loop.  Any help guiding me into the right area, or guiding me on how to start my loop would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not post pictures. Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Comment: "Traversal" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: Apologies @Alex, I'm obviously new to Stackoverflow. I removed the pics, and added code for sample dataframes.

Comment: Thanks @OpenSorceress